# Merging two lists into another list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

Suppose I have two lists like this,

```
Ii = [[7,1],[7,5],[7,8],[5,8],[2,8],[3,5]]
ci = [11,5,3,5,5,4]
```

Now I want to make another list (I) of m x n which will look like this,

```
I = 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[11, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I tried this code,

```
m,n = 8,10    
I = [[0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]
    for i, j in Ii:
        I[m - i][j - 1] = 1
```

Which have an output looks like this,

```
I = 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now I have 1 where I wanted the values of ci. But I want to put the values of ci in the places of 1. Need help regarding how can I do this?

Comment: What is `n` and what is `m`?

Comment: can you explain what is the logic behind creating `I` form `Ii` and `ci`?

Comment: Can you explain the logic by which the two input lists lead to the 4x4 list?  I thought for a second it might be "assign the values from the second list to the corresponding coordinates from the first list", but that's not what your sample output looks like.

Comment: Sorry for missing the information, m=4 and n=4 for 4x4 matrix (n is not used). The logic is creating a list which has a reverse index number in the vertical line (m-vertical) and (horizontal-1) in the horizontal index. but you can also directly use (i,j) as index no problem. I only need to know how to pass the values of ci to replace the 1s?

Comment: Henry bro it is saying list index out of range for 8x8 matrix.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check everyone. With a different example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m = 8 
n = 10 
Ii = [[7,1],[7,5],[7,8],[5,8],[2,8],[3,5]]
ci = [11,5,3,5,5,4]

I = [[0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]

for z, *j, in enumerate(Ii):
    for i, k in j:
        I[m-i][k-1] = ci[z]

for i in I:
    print(i)
```

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[11, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: bro Ii and ci will have same length but the output I can have different length.

Comment: It is not working for the following values:

m = 8
n = 10
Ii = [[7,1],[7,5],[7,8],[5,8],[2,8],[3,5]]
ci = [11,5,3,5,5,4]

Comment: Please check. The output is wrong. You need to put 11 in the (7,1) cell, 5 in the (7,5) cell, 3 in the (7,8) cell and so on. You are putting 11 in multiple cells.

Comment: You cannot call index number in any logic because it is not relatable. You need to search for  '1' in my code and replace it with values of ci.

Comment: No bro you are wrong. m can be any values. It is not related to Ii. Please check this code:

`m = 8
n = 10

Ii = [[7,1],[7,5],[7,8],[5,8],[2,8],[3,5]]

ci = [11,5,3,5,5,4]


I = [[0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]
for i, j in Ii:
    I[m - i][j - 1] = 1`

This will place 1 into all the places of Ii where I have used a reverse index method. It is never related to ci. and m is independent, you can put m=100 also this will work.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check it again Henry bro. With a different example.

Comment: thanks henry bro now it is working for both the examples. Can you please explain the logic behind your code? And how can i learn about the *j? is it pointer?

Comment: So-called ```extended sequence unpacking```, you can check this at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/  for more details. In short, collecting items into a ```list```.